# Android voice recording crashes (straight from Docs)

Tags: android, crash, record, voice

I've taken the code from Android's own [Audio Capture documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) and ran it to achieve just what the docs say. As is, the code crashes when I click the "Start Recording" button and the crash says the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
**at com.om.shout_o_meter.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:130)
at com.om.shout_o_meter.MainActivity.onRecord(MainActivity.java:111)
at com.om.shout_o_meter.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:109)
at com.om.shout_o_meter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I place `AudioRecordTest()` at the very beginning of the `startRecording()` method, the crash ceases until I finish the first recording and then press "Start Recording" again, the crash reappears with the following message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.om.shout_o_meter.MainActivity.stopRecording(MainActivity.java:135)
at com.om.shout_o_meter.MainActivity.onRecord(MainActivity.java:113)
at com.om.shout_o_meter.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:109)
at com.om.shout_o_meter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code I'm using is the exact same code as that of the docs (linked above), and the "MainActivity" file that the exception is pointing to can be found here: http://pastie.org/8682455

Any clue? what baffles me is that the code is pasted as is, straight from the docs, and still it fails..
Thanks

Comment: In the file that I've linked to at the bottom of the question, I've changed the creation of the buttons and the adding of the listeners from what is in the Docs to the ways that I am used to, just for the sake of clarity when I am working with the code. The exceptions originated from the first untouched version of the code (from Docs)

Comment: Please disregard, complete mistake. Classname had not matched the constructor provided from docs. Thanks for not banning